# Human (body or face) detection/recognition open source software?

Tags: face-detection

I have like a trillion of images in my disk and want to classify them basically in 2 groups:

- Those images which includes people (bodies or faces)
- Those images which does not include people

Any desktop software - preferably Open Source - to help me on this?

Comment: You might want to take this to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I imagine this is a common task for which a thousand different trained machine learning algorithms have been produced and are published open source. I personally do not know of any, though.

Comment: Depending on your expertise and how much time you're willing to put in, [this open source demo may suit you](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/). It requires you to train it on a sampling of images first, however. On the upside, it can identify particular people once you've trained it.

Answer (score 1):

[DigiKam](https://userbase.kde.org/Digikam/Face_Recognition) has a facial recognition module.

Comment: LR 6 also have, but IMHO both of them you need to train to recognize particular faces

Comment: Terminology — *face detection* is finding the location of human faces in an image, while *facial recognition* is identifying individuals.